# Generating an SAS Token on client side (using AngularJS) to upload a blob to Microsoft Azure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

I currently have a site built with HTML/Javascript and AngularJS.  I am having a hard time uploading an image to Azure as a blob because I do not know how I can generate an SAS Token. I am using an upload service found here https://github.com/kinstephen/angular-azure-blob-upload but require an SAS Token to get the file to upload.

Almost every example I find uses a backend to generate the token but this app is using AngularJS as its backend.

Comment: you don't have any server side code ? is it not possible to run a node js based api and call it from client side..?

Answer (score 1):

> Almost every example I find uses a backend to generate the token but
>   this app is using AngularJS as its backend.

There's a reason for using a server-side backend to generate the token. In order to generate a token, you would need account key. You could very well generate a SAS token using client-side JavaScript but in order to do that, you would need to expose the account key to your client application which is a big security risk because if someone has key to your account, they can do anything with your storage account. Thus it is recommended that you create SAS token using a server-side application so that you don't expose your account key.

If you still wish to create a SAS token using Client-Side JavaScript, please see [`Constructing a Service SAS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx). Essentially go to the section titled `Constructing the Signature String` at the bottom of that link and write code in JavaScript for that, and compute signature using account key.